# Increase amount of numbers for picking randomly

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, random, cmd

There is a batch file that looks for Pen=n in the list.txt and changes its value (n) randomly from the given row of ten numbers (set "var[pen]=1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10"). But if there are more than ten numbers say twenty (set "var[pen]=1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20") or hundred, it is still picking a number from first ten ones ignoring the rest.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "file=D:\list.txt"
set "temp=D:\temp.txt"
set "var[pen]=1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10" &

for /L %%i in (1,10,1%time:~-2%) do set "rand=!random!"

(for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims==" %%a in ("%file%") do (
   if defined var[%%a] (
      call :getRandomValue var="!var[%%a]!"
      echo %%a=!var!
   ) else if "%%b" neq "" (
      echo %%a=%%b
   ) else (
      echo %%a
   )
)) > "%temp%"

move /Y "%temp%" "%file%"

pause > nul && pause > nul
goto :EOF

:getRandomValue value="list"
set /A "rand=!random:~-1!+1"
for /F "tokens=%rand%" %%v in (%2) do set "%1=%%v"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

edit:
the list.txt contains a list of stuff like pen paper rubber etc. with the corresponding value next to it.

```
pen=5
pencil=43
paper=0
rubber=22
```

what the bat file does is just putting random number picking in up from the row of numbers provided. in the following case it would change the value of pen to a random number from 1 to 10. but if I add some extra numbers more than ten it will then just ignore them.

Comment: I honestly have no idea what your code is written to do, it makes no sense to me at all. It may help, if you [edit] your question and try to explain it. It would be greatly appreciated if, when you do that, you also provide along side it some sample content of `D:\list.txt`.

Comment: `set /A "rand=!random:~-1!+1"` chooses a number between `1` and `10`, if you want to select a random number between `1` and `20` change that line. Surely you haven't posted all of that just to ask us for code to pick a random whole number within a range! I would wager that the search facility could locate examples of that quite easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to specify the [origin post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Batch/comments/rnvn05/editing_ini_file/) of this problem. In such a post, there is not any specification about how the probabilities must be given, but all the 3 examples provided have 10 probable values, so I assumed that *all* probabilities have 10 values. The fix is add the number of probabilities each value can have:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Define the probabilities for new values
set "value[apple]=0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1" & set "num[apple]=10" & rem 0 (70%) or 1 (30%)
set "value[peach]=0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5" & set "num[peach]=10" & rem from 0 (50%) to 5 (the rest 50%)
set "value[banana]=54 68 82 96" & set "num[banana]=4" & rem each 25%

rem Randomize
for /L %%i in (1,10,1%time:~-2%) do set "ran=!random!"

(for /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%a in (input.ini) do (
   if defined value[%%a] (
      call :getRandomValue value=%%a
      echo %%a=!value!
   ) else if "%%b" neq "" (
      echo %%a=%%b
   ) else (
      echo %%a
   )
)) > output.ini

move /Y output.ini input.ini
goto :EOF


:getRandomValue value=item
set /A "ran=%random%%%num[%2]+1"
for /F "tokens=%ran%" %%v in ("!value[%2]!") do set "%1=%%v"
exit /B
```

You also forget (again) to provide the *real* format of the input file, that include `[headers]`:

```
[Berries]
Strawberry=1
Blackberry=-13
Blueberry=100
Cherry=6
[Fruits]
apple=0
peach=4
banana=18
orange=-2.5
[Vegetables]
Potato=44
Tomato=2
Onion=0
Garlic=17
```

**EDIT 2022/01/08:** *New method added as requested in comment*

As I already said, you have *not* specified the rules to define the probable values. I proposed a method that works correctly based on your first example, but then you define values that does *not* conform with my proposed method (10 possible values, like in your first example). I modified the method and *then* you invented values that does not conform either: *"Why 100 values?"* *"Because any number above 31 will make the method fail..."*

I modified the method (again) so you can define the probabilities via value:percent pairs. Here it is:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Define the probabilities for new values as value:percent pairs
set "value[apple]=23:17 68:83"                    & rem 23 at 17%, 68 at 83%
set "value[peach]=0:50 1:10 2:10 3:10 4:10 5:10"  & rem from 0 (50%) to 5 (the rest 50%)
set "value[banana]=54:25 68:25 82:25 96:25"       & rem each 25%

rem Randomize
for /L %%i in (1,10,1%time:~-2%) do set "ran=!random!"

(for /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%a in (input.ini) do (
   if defined value[%%a] (
      call :getRandomValue %%a
      echo %%a=!value!
   ) else if "%%b" neq "" (
      echo %%a=%%b
   ) else (
      echo %%a
   )
)) > output.ini

move /Y output.ini input.ini
goto :EOF


:getRandomValue item
set /A "ran=%random%%%100+1, val=0"
for %%a in (!value[%1]!) do for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%x in ("%%a") do (
   if %ran% gtr !val! set "value=%%x"
   set /A val+=%%y
)
exit /B
```

Comment: if you put num[apple]=100 and provide hundred probable numbers it wont work. Why 100? Obviously in order to deal with percents within the system you offered. For example there is no other way to set probability of 17% for apple=23 and 83% for apple=68. So there would be 100 numbers: 17 of 23s and 83 of 68s.

Comment: could you please help me to increase the number of probable values up to 100?

Comment: See my last edit...

Answer (score 0):

What you are aiming to do is to randomly index from a list, which requires you to first determine the number of items in the list.

one method of doing so:

```bat
@Echo off

 Set "var[pen]=a b c d e f g h i"

Rem enable enviroment for !expanison!
 Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

Rem Build 'array', splitting string on spaces and incrementing array size count
 Set _i=1& Set "item[1]=%var[pen]: =" & Set /A "_i+=1" & Set "item[!_i!]=%"

Rem index randomly from known array size [one indexed]
 For /f delims^= %%i in ('Set /A !random! %%!_i! + 1')Do Echo(Item:%%i = !Item[%%i]!
 Pause
```